# grab info from a form and append it in an xml file directly using php with closing tags '< >' entact

Tags: php, html, xml

I am new to php.This post might look lengthy but its nothing but a simple project .Here i am trying to get info from a from and fill an xml file with it .But to do so i must elements name closed with `<>` tags.I have used `&lt` and `&gt` entities in my php file.It gives desired output when i echo output on the browsers

output on firefox browser  **I WANT SIMELAR OUTPUT FOR MY XML FILE:**

[image]

but when i write to a xml file  the closing tags disappeared and &lt and &gt return back and the xml file looks messy,actually it doesn't look like an xml file at all.

Here is how it looks like in my xml file:

[image]

How i can solve this problem?

**Form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method='POST'>
    <fieldset style='padding-left:30px;width:300px;position:absolute;left:200px;background:lightblue;'>
    <legend style='font-size:20px;'>User Info</legend>
    Name:</br>
    <input type='text' placeholder='name' name='name' required></br></br>
    Email:</br>
    <input type='email' placeholder='email' name='email'></br></br>
    Gender :</br>
    <input type='radio' name='gender' id='male' value='male'><label for='male'>male</label></br>
    <input type='radio' name='gender' id='female' value='female'><label for='female'>female</label></br></br>
    Select fruit:</br>
    <select name='opts[]' size='4' style='width:160px;' multiple>
        <option value='apple'>apple</option>
        <option value='orange'>orange</option>
        <option value='pineapple'>pineapple</option>
        <option value='banana'>banana</option>
        <option value='lichi'>liche</option>
        <option value='jackfruit'>jackfruit</option>
        <option value='mango'>mango</option>
    </select>
    </br></br><hr>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['opts'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['opts'])){

            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $gender=$_POST['gender'];
            $fruits=$_POST['opts'];
            $fruitsample='';
            foreach($fruits as $elem){
                $fruitsample .='&ltfruit&gt'.$elem.'&lt/fruit&gt</br>';
            }
            $fav_fruits='&ltfavFruits&gt</br>'. $fruitsample.'&lt/favFruits&gt';
            $user='&ltname&gt'.$name.'&lt/name&gt';
            $mail='&ltemail&gt'.$email.'&lt/email&gt';
            $gend='&ltgender&gt'.$gender.'&lt/gender&gt';
            $final='&ltuser&gt</br>'.$user.'</br>'.$mail.'</br>'.$gend.'</br>'.$fav_fruits.'</br>&lt/user&gt</br>';
            echo $final;

            $filename='textIt.txt';
            $file=fopen($filename,'a');
            fwrite($file,$final);


        }else{
            echo 'you have ot select every field';
        }

}
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Next to that you do a little mistake by writing the XML on your own with string concatenation instead of using one of the common PHP XML libraries that prevent having such issues automatically.

Comment: i actually didn't know such libraries exists.thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this PHP method.
[PHP DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php/)
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

Comment: this qualifies more as a comment than an answer.

Comment: True. (Need more points before I can comment).